# string indexer works localy but not when site is hosted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following problem with java script.

I have *jQuery* object. Locally getting i-th symbol of its value i use following code $(this).val()[i];

When i deployed this code in server this line started throwing exception saying that $(this).val()[i] is undefined and instead of it i used $(this).val().charAt(i) function; charAt() function works fine both in server and local.

I can't understand how this kind of issue could happen as the same script is being executed in same browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine how it being hosted would make any difference either, and can only assume something *else* is different as well, not just the hosting.

But you still need to use the `charAt` syntax. A large number of people are still using browsers with JavaScript engines that don't support the `[]` notation for accessing characters.